Css vertical-rl does not rotate korean characters

I'm applying writing-mode: vertical-rl; to a div tag containing the word "A중385" but it only changes the direction of "A385" and the word 중 doesn't change direction. Please help me solve this problem.
I am use css writing-mode: vertical-rl; but it's not working
this is my sample code:
.vertical{
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}

<div class="vertical">
    A중385
</div>


Korean vertical writing does not rotate the characters. If you want to rotate all characters, use a rotation transform or sideways writing mode.

Solution I can think of is to manually rotate the 중 ot use text-orientation: sideways


.vertical {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: mixed;
}

.vertical span.rotate {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate(90deg); 
}


.vertical1 {
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: sideways;
}
<div class="vertical">
    A<span class="rotate">중</span>385
</div>

<br> <br> 
<div class="vertical1">
    A중385
</div>




thank you so much, I followed you and used text-orientation: sideways; and it worked!!
